# I'cant change the log level for log4j2 implementation to websphere log level at runtime from "Logs and trace" option

Tags: java, websphere, log4j2

I use log4j2 to implement loggin for applications than run over websphere application server 9. 
I need the log level change at runtime, i do this from Administrative Console, on "Logs and trace" option. But, the change has not effect.
It's possible make this over Websphere with log4j2 implementation ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to change Log4j log levels through Websphere's Administrative Console. 
The WebSphere Administrative Console can only change log levels for WebSphere's internal Logger objects and java.util.logging.Loggers in your application.

You should instead locate your log4j configuration file and configure the log levels from there.

Comment: Hi Frank. We decide use java.util.loggin (JUL) according to IBM document https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/techjournal/0802_supauth/0802_supauth-pdf.pdf

Comment: In the scope of Websphere, that's definitely the better approach than using Log4J in the long run.